# Preg_match doesn't work while trying to get numbers in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hum.. I mean I can't make it work... 
So here is what I did..

```
$url = 'http://test/test/9244349';
$test = preg_match('#\d*#', $url, $matches);
```

array (size=1)
0 => string '' (length=0)

I just want to catch "9244349" but I don't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `*` with `+`, if you want to match digits, there's no point in a pattern that matches, zero digits, too, is there?

```
preg_match('/\d+/','http://test/test/9244349',$matches);
echo $matches[0];//output:9244349
```

Comment: Thank you I read a small tutorial about regex.
And it says that x+ is using to get x, if it appears at least one time.. So why it isn't working here?

Answer (score 1):

Let's play regex engine:

- `\d*` means any number of digits. Including zero.
- We start at the beginning of the string. We see an `h`.
- `h` doesn't match `\d`.
- But - we're also allowed to match zero repetitions of `\d`. So the empty string *before* `h` matches.
- We've reached the end of the regex, and we've found a match.
- Achievement unlocked!
- (of course, it's a match of zero characters, but that's OK. A Perl-compatible regex will always return the leftmost possible match, even if there may be further matches up ahead in the string that could be longer).

So, as mentioned in other posts, change the `*` to `+` to force at least one digit to match, then the rest will follow.

You could also use `preg_match_all()`, but then you'd get a lot of empty matches, one for each position between two non-digits...

Answer (score 0):

Change `*` to `+` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

This is [**basename**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
echo basename($url);
```

Comment: Works in this case, but `http://test/test/9244349?id=123` will return `9244349?id=123`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Yes, but that could be handled if you are a smart one and I would like to handle this in `(int)basename($url);` this way as long as I know how I constructed the URLs